# Azure AI studio OCR enhancements

Tags: azure, azure-openai

I am using Azure AI studio and I have enabled the enhancements button. However, it seems that the API call does not include OCR enhancements, because the source code is not showing the  OCR enhancements.

Comment: Hi can you give more  details like, the OCR service you are using and share a snippet of your API call source code.

Answer (score 0):

It's known issue in the Azure AI studio in the source code, For the playground of Azure AI studio, although the source code doesn't reflect the OCR enhancements which should be included in the "show raw JSON", but it does effective in turned on state.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're experiencing with the OCR enhancements not showing in the API call could be related to the specific version of the OCR service you are using.
According to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/computer-vision/concept-ocr), all future OCR enhancements will be part of Computer Vision v 4.0.

To solve the issue, you can use Image `Analysis 4.0 REST API` or client SDK which use  `api-version=2023-10-01`.
With Image Analysis 4.0 Analyze API, you can use select from various analysis options. Below is sample URL with selected features:

```bash
https://<endpoint>/computervision/imageanalysis:analyze?api-version=2023-10-01&features=tags,read,caption,denseCaptions,smartCrops,objects,people
```

For more details and examples, you can check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/computer-vision/how-to/call-analyze-image-40?pivots=programming-language-rest-api).